# Running Qiskit Circuit Composer locally on Jupyer Notebook

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I was wondering if I could use Qiskit locally on Jupyter Notebook and thus loaded my IBM-Q account via API token. I could construct circuits execute jobs but when I tried to use circuit composer, it returned nothing like the interactive circuit-composer as it does in IBM Quantum Lab. I ran the following code:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, IBMQ 
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
from ibm_quantum_widgets import *
%matplotlib inline
from ibm_quantum_widgets import CircuitComposer
CircuitComposer()
```

It returned the following:

```
CircuitComposer(circuit=<qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit.QuantumCircuit object at 0x15C528F8>)
```

Is there anything I am possibly missing out?
p.s qiskit has the latest version installed.

Answer (score 3):

Before running the local notebook, you need to enable the `ibm_quantum_widgets` extension. You can check if it is enable with `jupyter nbextension list`.

Otherwise, you can enable it, for example, like this:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py --user ibm_quantum_widgets
```

Or by the [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator server](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator), typically in http://127.0.0.1:8888/nbextensions :

[image]